# Why does force including precompiled headers work at all?

Tags: c++, build, compiler-construction, pch

Apparently it is recommended to force include precompiled headers, so that the source may be used with and without precompiled headers. Even CMake uses the [force include method](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/target_precompile_headers.html) on precompiled headers.

However for example Microsofts MSVC [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/build/reference/yu-use-precompiled-header-file?view=vs-2019) says:

> The compiler treats all code occurring before the .h file as precompiled. It **skips to just beyond the #include directive associated with the .h file**, uses the code contained in the .pch file, and then compiles all code after filename.

and for the `/FI`option the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/build/reference/fi-name-forced-include-file?view=vs-2019) says:

> This option has the same effect as specifying the file with double quotation marks in an #include directive on the **first** line of every source file specified on the command line, in the CL environment variable, or in a command file.

So to summarize this: All includes that are **above/before** an include directive of a corresponding precompiled header, will be precompiled into the PCH file. Force-including that file will put this in the first line of a file.

My question now is: How does this work together? Is there some special logic for PCH files during build process or am I missing something?

**Update:** I checked the [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html) as well and it looks like that gcc searches for precompiled headers for each include directive it finds and uses precompiled headers if possible. So do I understand it correctly that MSVC kind of summarizes all includes **before (including the header itself)** an include that should be used to generate a precompiled header, where gcc instead generates a precompiled header for that specific header?

If that's right it arises the question: Is gcc really way more flexible regarding preocmpiled header usage and how *easy* it is to gain a performance boost during compilation out of it?

Comment: Not sure about how this actually works, but I think you may be misrepresenting your first quote in the summary. The quote says "The compiler treats all code occurring before the .h file as precompiled." It does not say it will precompile it. It says it _treats_ it as precompiled, probably meaning, it expects skipping it to not have any adverse effects, because the .pch should contain any effects it might have had if not skipped.

Comment: The compilation itself takes place when using `/Yc` [to create the PCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/build/reference/yc-create-precompiled-header-file?view=vs-2019) doesn't it? And there it reads the same way. I really wonder what's going on there.

Comment: So what's the question ? ;p

Comment: The question is: How is the compilation speedup with PCHs achieved when they are force included before all other headers? If the compiler treats all lines before the PCH as precompiled and it gets force included, doesn't the compiler treat effectively no line as precompiled? Will the preprocessor be able to identify include lines that are part of the PCH and skip them? Does the compiler's frontend still have to do some work to identify parts of the translation unit that are already part of the PCH? 

So basically I'm looking for in-depth insights into that topic to understand it better.